# Finding Duplicates in a String - Order Complexity

Tags: java

Could someone verify if the order complexity of this code is n(logn)? if it is not can you please explain your answer? I really appreciate the help

```
  public static boolean isDuplicate(String s){
        char[] sArray = s.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<sArray.length/2;i++){
            for(int j=sArray.length/2+1;j<sArray.length;j++){
                if(sArray[i] == sArray[j])
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the log here?

Comment: i think this is O(n^2)

Comment: Verifying if this code is O(n log(n))... No it's not.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not, it's O(n^2), because you are iterating over the whole array in the outer loop, and for each value of `i`, you are also iterating over the whole array in the inner loop. The fact that you split the array in two doesn't change the order complexity.

If you want to find duplicates with a O(n*log(n)) algorithm, you can sort the array, and check for duplicates on the adjacent places, like that :

```
public static boolean isDuplicate(String s){
    char[] sArray = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(sArray); // O(n*log(n))
    for (int i=0; i<sArray.length-1; i++) // O(n)
        if (sArray[i]==sArray[i+1])
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Even better, you can use a `HashSet`, and find duplicates in O(n) :

```
public static boolean isDuplicate(String s){
    HashSet<Character> alreadySeenChars = new HashSet<Character>();
    char[] sArray = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<sArray.length; i++) { // O(n)
        if (alreadySeenChars.contains(sArray[i])) // O(1)
            return true;
        alreadySeenChars.add(sArray[i]); // O(1)
    }
    return false;
}
```